# Design database for 1 to 1 relationship when some columns are applicable only in certain cases

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a users table which stores the details of two types of users namely students and teachers. There are 10 fields like username, password etc common to both students and teachers. There are no 1 to n relations in case of any data here.

In case of students, I have to store twenty different 1 to 1 data like weight, DOB, Admission No., Parent,Phone number etc.

In case of teachers, I have to store a separate set of twenty 1 to 1 data like email id, affiliation number etc which is not related to students in any way.

What is the best database structure I can use in this scenario from below? If there are better options please provide that too.

1. One table with 50 columns where 20 columns will have NULL in case of students and 20 columns will have NULL in case of teachers
2. One table with 30 columns where first 10 columns stores common data and next 20 columns store students details in case of student and teacher's data in case of teacher.
3. Two tables one with 10 column to store user details. And another table with 20 columns to store students details in case of student and teacher's data in case of teacher.
4. Three tables one with 10 column to store user details. Another table with 20 columns to store students details and yet another table with 20 columns to store  teacher's data

Comment: option 4., it's a classic super/subtype pattern.

Comment: option 4, no doubt. Think of it from an object oriented perspective - the table with 10 columns is the base object and the students and teachers tables are the derived objects.

Comment: Option 4 is the most normalized, but depending on usage, I'd consider denormalizing to two tables with 30 columns each.   One table for students, one for teachers.   The first 10 columns of both tables would be the same.

Comment: @TabAlleman What if a student becomes a teacher? :)

Comment: @dean they would have a record in both tables.   It's not the end of the world.   : )

Comment: @TabAlleman Sure, but then you have to change the password in two tables...

Comment: @dean True, unless they have a different login as a teacher than they do as a student.   But that's why I say "depending on usage"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single Table Inheritance and Class Table Inheritance are both fine. In fact Fowler has recommended STI for agile. And if you use a good ORM like Hibernate, the difference is trivial. If you use PostgreSQL your nulls won't take up any extra space either.

That being said, you should further normalize your tables (parents phone #s should be in a diff table for example). See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831 for some help

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember the principles of relational design. All the columns should be dependent on the key fields and only on the key fields.

Its better to have choice 4 tables:

```
1) For a base person details (columns teachers and students both have).
2) A teacher table for details that pertain to only teachers. This will relate to base person table with a foreign key (just like table 3).
3) A student table for details that pertain to only students.
```

No extra empty columns and very flexible in the kind of queries (some of which that you are not anticipating) you will be able to do.

Comment: You say "4 tables", but list only 3??

Comment: I meant choice 4. But you may want to create a many to many table because a given student may have many teachers. And each teacher may have many students.

Answer (score 0):

the First thing I thought of was a pigs ear relationship, a link entity so that you could have ID, teacherID, studentID to show which teachers teach which students, but then I realised this isn't what you asked for so...

Why not just have a single boolean, true if teacher, false if not?

Answer (score 0):

Look up these two tags:  [single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)

These correspond to well known techniques that are like option 1 and option 4.  There are situations where one or the other of these is best. The tag wikis (info) and the questions grouped under the tags will give you some additional help.